# Userform activating the sheet where it was initiated first

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform with few buttons for different macros to run. At the end of execution of macro it hides the userfrom. I have resablled the close button of userform with the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose _
  (Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
'   Prevents use of the Close button
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        hmm
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

hmm hides the userfrom. Now the challenge is suppose there are 3 workbook.

1. Workbook A: The macro enabled workbook in which I have written the code for userform and sub routines
2. Workbook B: Where I press the key combination and this shows the userfrom
3. Workbook C: Where I want to execute same macro with the help of same userfrom

Now when I press key combination (while Workbook C is activated) it activates other workbook (the one where I initiated the userfrom first) and then show the userfrom. Though when I press the some button on userfrom it runs the relevant macro but activates the workbook where the form was initiated first.

I want to keep the same workbook activated where this key combination was pressed to show the userfrom (so it do not go to the previous workbook). Please help

The Code:

This is the key combinantion and has been saved in ThisWorkbook of Microsoft Excel Objects

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "%{s}", "LoadMenu"
End Sub
```

These procedures are in a code module and loads and hides the userfrom (named as MainMenu)

```
Private Sub LoadMenu()

MainMenu.Show

End Sub



Sub hideMenu()

MainMenu.Hide

End Sub
```

This is an example sub routine which is run when we click a button on the userfrom,

```
Sub highlightYellow()
    selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    hideMenu ' This hides menu after the execution
End Sub
```

Now once i have run the macro on some workbook (by calling the userform first time and by clicking a button on it) for the first time like as I said before, and then when I go to some other workbook and then again press this key combination it takes me back to the first workbook when I used this thing for the first time and when I press the highlighting button it highlights the workbook where I pressed the key combination but at the end do not know why the first workbook automatically becomes activate.

Please refer the below link for the workbook,  please open 2-3 new workbooks and then try on them together.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/952lrsrsglt9f6y/Test%20Book.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: To answer this question, it would be great to have the code which is run when you press the shortcut key.

Comment: This is how it works on my computer: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wlug6riweqmf7s/selectionWrb.avi?dl=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All userforms as objects. Separate them at every run to have independent instances.
Try this

```
Private Sub LoadMenu()
    Dim frmTemp as MainMenu

    Set frmTemp = New MainMenu
    frmTemp.Show
    Unload frmTemp
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, tried this. This creates a new userfrom every time so if i am adding text box and somebody has filled some data in that it gets automatically deleted once we again press the key combination.

Comment: Yes, as now at each run a fresh instance of user form is being called, it won't have any data saved in it. If you need to save and re-load any old data, you will have store that some where and load it in your form. My suggestion is use `SaveSetting` and `GetSetting`.